# Functional testing with Rails and Devise. What to put in my fixtures?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, functional-testing, fixtures

Hi I'm wanting to do some functional testing of my Rails 3 app that uses Devise and CanCan.

In my User model I have the users age, I want to test that a user can only visit a certain page if they are:

1. Logged in
2. Over 35

I have seen in the Devise document that I can use: *sign_in* and I have put it in my tests and it appears to work - the test doesn't error because I have:

```
include Devise::TestHelpers
```

in my *test_helper.rb*

When I take it out my test does error because *sign_in* is not defined. So it is not a helper problem.

When I run the test and check to see if *span#loggedin* has one occurrence the test fails because there is 0 occurrences. *span#loggedin* only appears *if user_signed_in?*

What do I need to put in my fixtures or tests to create a test user who is also a fully signed up user (confirmed etc)?

View Code:

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
     <span id="loggedin">User is signed in</span>
     User age is <span id="age"><%= current_user.age.to_s %></span>
<% end %>
```

Test Code:

```
test "should get index" do
    sign_in :one
    get :index
    assert_response :success
    assert_select 'span#loggedin', :count => 1
end
```

Fixture:

```
one:
 email: jez@example.com
 age: 36
```

It works okay in development when I manually login but I'm hoping to automate it all - the point of testing really!!

Answer (score 66):

**Solution for Devise pre 3.2.0**

I think this might be what you are looking for:

```
User.new.send(:password_digest, 'password')
```

It works when the salt is nil.

And therefore in your fixture you can do this:

```
one:
  email: 'some@user.com'
  encrypted_password: <%= User.new.send(:password_digest, 'password') %>
```

---

**Solution for Devise versions 3.2.0 to 3.5.0**

At Devise 3.2.0, a [method was created precisely for this purpose](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/commit/31971e69e6a1bcf6c7f01eaaa44f227c4af5d4d2) (@Inkling update). For these versions the encrypted_password should be defined like this:

```
encrypted_password: <%= Devise.bcrypt(User, 'password') %>
```

where `User` is the class of your user model.

*Note that this only applies if you're using the default encryption algorithm (bcrypt).*

---

**Solution for Devise versions 3.5.1 and above**

As [Katarzyna](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1576481/katarzyna) has pointed out: [Device.bcrypt has been deprecated](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/commit/a8769933d1842e8dff1a625d202f693403663e12#diff-19b4dd928714c72f1338874351e8ff2d) in version 3.5.1. From that version on, the encrypted_password should be defined like this:

```
encrypted_password: <%= Devise::Encryptor.digest(User, 'password') %>
```

Comment: If you're new to an app and not sure what encryption algorithm Devise is using, check the config/initializers/devise.rb file for the `config.encryptor` setting. Another clue is if the Gemfile includes `gem 'devise-encryptable'` (which is used to pick anything other than bcrypt for encryption).

Comment: Devise.bcrypt is deprecated; use Devise::Encryptor.digest

Comment: I'm getting an uninitialized constant Devise::Encryptor when using the above code.. any ideas?

Comment: @BrianDear are you using a pre-3.5.1 version of Devise? If so, you should try one of the other options (3.2 to 3.5: bcrypt, pre-3.2: password_digest) or update your version of Devise.

Comment: Thanks! this is still valid as of Feb 2019

Answer (score 8):

I have sorted out the problem - I was logging in the user incorrectly.

My test should hare read:

```
test "should get index" do
    @user = users(:one)
    sign_in @user
    get :index
    assert_response :success
    assert_select 'span#loggedin', :count => 1
 end
```

This also works and eliminates a line of code:

```
test "should get index" do
    sign_in users(:one)
    get :index
    assert_response :success
    assert_select 'span#loggedin', :count => 1
end
```

My understanding of Fixtures was lacking ...

But back to the question - what to put in fixtures:

```
one:
 email: jez@example.com
 encrypted_password: $2a$10$PoBe1MvkoGJsjMVTEjKqgeBUp.xdfzWoiDjBzQhtLAj16NqIa2fOy
 password_salt: $2a$10$PoBe1MvkoGJsjMVTEjKqge
 reset_password_token: nil
 remember_token: nil
 remember_created_at: nil
 sign_in_count: 1
 current_sign_in_at: 2011-01-02 08:31:23
 last_sign_in_at: 2011-01-02 08:31:23
 current_sign_in_ip: 127.0.0.1
 last_sign_in_ip: 127.0.0.1
 confirmation_token: nil
 confirmed_at: 2011-01-02 08:31:23
 confirmation_sent_at: 2011-01-02 08:30:59
 failed_attempts: 0
 unlock_token: nil
 locked_at: nil
 authentication_token: nil
 created_at: 2011-01-02 08:30:59
 updated_at: 2011-01-02 08:31:23
 age: 36
```

Now it works. If there is an easier that generating a user in dev and pasting the data into a fixture please do post.

Comment: You can use ERB in your fixtures, that will help you make the fixtures easier to maintain. You could use tools like FactoryGirl instead of (or in combination with) fixtures, this will make your tests easier to maintain, but will slow down your tests significantly.

Comment: I know about using ERB in my fixtures but what ERB do I need to generate the fixture above? That was the heart of my question - specifically what do I need to put in my fixtures?

Comment: I know this is an oldie, but I stumbled upon it looking for help in a similar scenario. My experiments indicate that simply adding a `confirmed_at` timestamp to your fixture seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Just one more hint. This worked great for me:

http://brandonhilkert.com/blog/managing-login-passwords-for-capybara-with-minitest-and-rails-fixtures/

And it seems to be DRY and nice solution.

Answer (score 1):

It's working for me.

I didn't change anything on my user fixture, it's like this:

```
one:
  id: 1
  name: MyString
  email: mystring@test.com
  group_id: 2
  encrypted_password: <%= Devise.bcrypt(User, 'password') %>
```

But I changed my `test_helper.rb` and I added this to the class `ActionController` (this will work for all controllers tests):

```
class ActionController::TestCase
    include Devise::TestHelpers

    setup do
        sign_in users(:one)
    end
end
```