# performance testing with devise authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

How can I run performance tests with devise. Using the Devise docs I have this in my test_helper.rb

```
class ActionController::TestCase
  include Devise::TestHelpers
end
```

From [Functional testing with Rails and Devise. What to put in my fixtures?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4577737/functional-testing-with-rails-and-devise-what-to-put-in-my-fixtures), I have this in my performance test:

```
require 'test_helper'
require 'rails/performance_test_help'

class EditorTest < ActionDispatch::PerformanceTest

  def test_create

    @user = users(:one)
    sign_in @user

    get 'documents/new/1'
  end

end
```

I get the following error

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `sign_in' for #<EditorTest:0xb6bc0654 ...>
    /test/performance/editor_test.rb:9:in `test_create'
```

How do I properly include the Devise TestHelpers in a performance test?

Thank you!

[edit]

This works as a functional test.

[edit]

After including the devise helper in ActionDispatch::PerformanceTest and running the test with ruby -d, here is the bottom of the debug output:

> ```
> /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/devise-1.1.rc2/lib/devise/test_helpers.rb:
>
> 53: warning: instance variable @request not initialized 
> Exception `NoMethodError' at /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ 
> activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/whiny_nil.rb:48 - undefined 
> method `env' for nil:NilClass 
> EEditorTest#test_create (0 ms warmup) 
> /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/devise-1.1.rc2/lib/devise/test_helpers.rb:
>
> 53: warning: instance variable @request not initialized 
> Exception `NoMethodError' at /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ 
> activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/whiny_nil.rb:48 - undefined 
> method `env' for nil:NilClass 
> E        process_time: 0 ms 
> Exception `Errno::EEXIST' at /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/fileutils.rb:243 -
> ```
>
> File 
>       exists - tmp/performance 
>       Exception `Errno::EEXIST' at /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/fileutils.rb:243 -
>   File 
>       exists - tmp/performance 
>       Exception`Errno::EEXIST' at /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/fileutils.rb:243 -
>   File 
>       exists - tmp/performance

The short version of the above error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `env' for nil:NilClass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems performance tests don't set a `request` variable, which Devise test helpers try to access. In other words, Devise test helpers won't help you here.

As suggested to you here http://groups.google.com/group/plataformatec-devise/browse_thread/thread/b50bfd8ecb24822c try filling in the sign in form like in integration tests.

This explains how integration tests work, with an example how to sign in: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#integration-testing

Answer (score 2):

(Misread question original reply to the wrong question is below.)

Try adding

```
class ActionDispatch::PerformanceTest
  include Devise::TestHelpers
end
```

to the bottom of your helper file.

---

(Original reply)

Make sure

```
class ActionController::TestCase
  include Devise::TestHelpers
end
```

is all the way at the bottom of your helper file. It should NOT be inside the `ActiveSupport::TestCase` class.

Comment: it's at the bottom. and, functional tests are already working. it's just performance tests.

Comment: see my edit above. I posted the error from your suggestion along with partial debug output.

Comment: See my other answer. Based on Jose Valim's answer to your question on google groups, my other answer should be the correct one (i.e. you won't be able to use the sign_in helper for performance tests).