# functional test: NomethodError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i'm a beginner in ruby on rails(and english :)), and i'm trying to use functional test but i had an error at fist

```
1)Error:
test_should_get_new(MicropostControllerTest)
NoMethodError: undefined method 'microposts' for nil:NilClass
```

My micropost_controller_test.rb

```
require 'test_helper'
class MicropostControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  test "should get new" do
    get :new
    assert_response :success
  end
end
```

My micropost_controller.rb

```
class MicropostController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @post = Micropost.new
    @posts = current_user.microposts.all
  end
  def create
    @post = current_user.microposts.create(:content => params[:content])
    logger.debug "New post: #{@post.attributes.inspect}"
    logger.debug "Post should be valid: #{@post.valid?}"
    if @post
    redirect_to micropost_new_path
    else
  end
  end
end
```

I tried to put something in microposts.yml but it didn't work. 
So, where i can find microposts method for functional test and how do i fix that?? Please help me?

p/s: My app still work in localhost

Comment: `current_user` returns `nil`.

Comment: @mayoneQD You have mentioned `current_user` in your controller but in test controller spec you don't have specified any user so it is null try to define `user` before executing the test

Comment: @anusha Thank you, i understand, but how do i put user in controller test, i try to setup user = users(:one) but it didn't work

Comment: @mayoneQD try following the @Alireza's answer if you are using `devise` for authentication

Comment: i have found out, i just put my helper in controller_test, then i can login user normally :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using **Devise** for user authentication then you need to authenticate and set `current_user` in your `MicropostController`, by for instance having a `before_action` as follows:

```
class MicropostController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def new
    @post = Micropost.new
    @posts = current_user.microposts.all
  end
# rest of the code
end
```

In your test you need to import devise test helpers as follows, if you haven't done it in your `test_helper`

```
class MicropostControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
 include Devise::TestHelpers
end
```

You can then use the `sign_in` method to sign in a user using Fixtures in your test. search for some tutorials on that or check the response here to get some clue: [Functional testing with Rails and Devise. What to put in my fixtures?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4577737/functional-testing-with-rails-and-devise-what-to-put-in-my-fixtures)

Comment: Your answer is relly help, i can learn much more,though it doesn't work now but i think i should try harder to find out :)