# How to test if devise is signing users in with login, not email?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, devise, bdd

I'm trying to confirm whether `devise` is using login, not email for sign in. That's what I have so far:

`test/controllers/sessions_controller_test.rb`:

```
require 'test_helper'

class Devise::SessionsControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  test "should sign in using login" do
    @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
    post :create, user: {login: 'login', password: 'password'}
    assert_response :success
  end
end
```

And now it says:

```
  1) Error:
Devise::SessionsControllerTest#test_should_sign_in_using_login:
NoMethodError: undefined method `authenticate?' for nil:NilClass
    test/controllers/sessions_controller_test.rb:7:in `block in <class:SessionsControllerTest>'
```

Why doesn't it work? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error disappeared after I added `include Devise::TestHelpers` in `test/test_helper.rb` as [documentation](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#test-helpers) suggests:

```
class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  ...
  include Devise::TestHelpers
end
```

And now my tests look this way:

`test/controllers/sessions_controller_test.rb`:

```
require 'test_helper'

class Devise::SessionsControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  test "should have login field" do
    @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
    get :new
    assert_select '[name="user[login]"]'
  end

  test "should sign in using login" do
    @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
    post :create, user: {login: 'login', password: 'password'}
    assert_redirected_to root_url
  end
end
```

`test/fixtures/users.yml` ([how to put password in a fixture](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10427785/52499)):

```
one:
    login: login
    encrypted_password: <%= Devise.bcrypt(User, 'password') %>
```