# Rails minitest BCrypt::Errors::InvalidHash:

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, minitest, bcrypt, digest

I've been following Hartl's Rails Tutorial and I am implementing minitests to my Login. Currently, everything works fine, and the user is able to login successfully.

But when I run the test on my Login Integration, I keep getting this error when I try to digest the token....

```
BCrypt::Errors::InvalidHash: invalid hash
  app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:13:in `create'
  test/integration/users_login_test.rb:21:in `block in <class:UsersLoginTest>'
  app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:13:in `create'
  test/integration/users_login_test.rb:21:in `block in <class:UsersLoginTest>'
```

Can someone help me understand this error and how I may be able to fix it please.

**Model**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :district
  belongs_to :school

  ###Why doesn't this work?------
  def User.digest(token)
    Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(token.to_s)
  end

end
```

**Fixtures** (users.yml)

```
tom:
  district_id: 1
  school_id: 6
  firstName: Tommy
  lastName: Pickles
  username: pickleman
  email: pickleman@gmail.com

  ###Error on this line------
  password_digest: <%= User.digest('password') %>
```

**Integration**(user_login_test.rb)

```
require 'test_helper'

class UsersLoginTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  def setup
    @user = users(:tom)
  end

  test "login with valid information" do
    get login_path

    ###Error on Sign Up Here------
    post sessions_path, session: { username: @user.username, password: 'password' }

    assert_redirected_to district_district_resources_path(@user.district)
    follow_redirect!
    assert_template 'sessions/new'
    assert_select "a[href=?]", login_path, count: 0
  end

end
```

**Controller**

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  #create session for login
  def create
    user = User.find_by(username: params[:session][:username]) if defined? params[:session][:username]  
    district = user.district if user
    school = user.school if user

    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password]) && district
        user_sign_in user
        redirect_to district_district_resources_path(district)
    else
        flash.now[:error] = 'Invalid username / password combination' # Not quite right!
        render 'new'
    end

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a work around.

Created a user with the password: password

I then directly added the password_digest that was generated into the users.yml for minitest to work.

users.yml

```
tom:
  district_id: 1
  school_id: 6
  firstName: Tommy
  lastName: Pickles
  username: pickleman
  email: pickleman@gmail.com

  ###HERE----
  password_digest: $2a$10$g/A4D6KtaLtxvm2lZ8C.vuPvl8Zu2TrbnPYpM6r59Wu397hlY42GO
```

Answer (score 2):

`BCrypt::Errors::InvalidHash` is raised when the hash stored in `password_digest` is not a valid BCrypt hash.

In short, you cannot just dump any SHA1 in there, you'll need to create a hash like this:

```
sha1_password = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(token.to_s)
BCrypt::Password.create(sha1_password).to_s
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11038412/473467) for a longer explanation on this topic.

Comment: When I do this, my entire login stops working, the user gets redirected as if the user is not logged in.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to generate a password for minitest test via fixtures, then I suggest you look at this: [Functional testing with Rails and Devise. What to put in my fixtures?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4577737/functional-testing-with-rails-and-devise-what-to-put-in-my-fixtures/10427785#10427785)